# Concatenate data from duplicate IDs into a single row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm collecting responses from a Google Form where each user has an ID and can send multiple form responses. I'd like to have only one row for each ID and concatenate multiple form responses into one row containing all that ID's data.

I illustrated my question in the link below.

[Editable Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AwD3RlgJv2ibrQVrcqK_el6mLV6sTGno-VTDWFAjK_g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you considered using Apps Script to do it? With SpreadsheetApp you have many options to work with your data. See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(C2:G<>""; "♦"&A2:A&"♥"&B2:B&"♥♠"&C2:G&"♥♠"; );;99^99));;99^99); "♦")); "♠"); 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1");;99^99)); "♥")))
```

[image: 0]